# Read more script problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, substring

I'm currently on a read more script but I have 3 small problems.

1. If I'm clicking on the link the first time the text is directly popping up instead of the toggle animation (The animation is not being displayed), why?
2. How can I ensure, that there is no html tag being cut like `br`, `b`, `paragraph`  and so on?
3. Currently there is also a small problem with the position of the link. Somehow the link is on a new line after the 3rd click. If I look at the source (in the browser) I see that there is a `display: block` but I haven't added any design except that design here:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       var readMoreText = "Read more..",
           readLessText = "Read less..";

       $(".entry-text").each(function() {    
           var link = $("<a href='' class='read-more'>Read more..</a>");

           if($(this).text().length > 700) 
           {
               $(this).html("<span>" + $(this).html().substr(0, 700) + "</span><span style='display: none'>" + $(this).html().substr(150) + "</span>");
               $(this).append("&nbsp;");
               $(this).append(link);
           }
       });   

       $(document).on("click", "a.read-more", function(event) {
           event.preventDefault();

           if($(this).text() == readMoreText)
               $(this).text(readLessText).prev().slideToggle("fast");
           else
               $(this).text(readMoreText).prev().slideToggle("fast");
       });
   });
   ```

EDIT: Added a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/svkrp0te/

Comment: Please show us the relevant HTML.  You may be able to only use some animation operations on block-level elements, not inline elements.

Comment: i've added a jsfiddle now, but somehow my first problem does not occur there but i can't post all the html & css stuff, it's simply too much.

Comment: Ok, sry i was wrong, the bug is also existing in the jsfiddle example.